# access android camera from android browser plugin

Tags: android, plugins, browser

I want to develop plugin for android default browser that has to invoke android native camera.
And I have the following doubts regarding this.

1. Does android default browser support plugins.
2. Is there any possibility to access android camera from android browser plugin.

Guide me how and where to start. Any tutorial or link reference is better. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer:

1. No.
2. see 1.

Longer answer:

Google is apparently planning to add extensions to Chrome in the future, but as of now, see 1.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.If possible give some link reference for this.And do you know how does flash work in android browser?

Comment: Sorry I currently don't have a source for this at hand. Regarding flash for Android > 2.3 see answer 1.